# Zillow Neighborhood data and STDistance

Tags: t-sql, geometry, geospatial, shapes, zillow

I am working with Zillow neighborhood data provided freely at http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm . I have successfully Imported the data with SRID 4120. Now I am trying to find out the neighborhoods by giving a coordinate(lat,long) and a radius. Finding a neighborhood in which my point exists is easy and is done through STIntersect method. I am actually confused with STDistance. For complete WA state data, It is giving me a maximum distaince of 4.xxx relative to any point in the wa. My question is what is the good way to find the points which are in a given radius and what is the unit.

thanx

zAfar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I was importing geography data into geometry column.